# Mime тип из названия файла или расширения

Tags: php, mime

Нужно как-то узнать mime-тип из названия файла или его расширения. Известно только расширение файла, например, "html". Надо как-нибудь узнать его mime-тип с помощью php.

Comment: Вариант -- перебор вас устроит?
Другого, честно, не знаю.

Comment: http://www.manhunter.ru/webmaster/302_opredelenie_mime_type_fayla_po_ego_rasshireniyu.html
нашел ответ

Answer (score 3):

Большинство plain-text файлов, такие как: txt, htm(l), xml и т.д., не имеют MIME-типа. Эти файлы содержат всего лишь последовательность печатаемых символов.

Если вы планируете использовать, то что вы нашли на продакшене, то не удивляйтесь [LFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_File_Inclusion), [RCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_code_execution).

Чтобы определить mime-тип достаточно использовать массив с заголовками известных вам файлов, которые будут хранится в hex ([bin2hex()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.bin2hex.php) + в помощь [не плохой ресурс](http://open-file.ru/)), [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) для чтения первых ~5-10 байт от начала файла. Далее, регулярками парсите входные данные, с которыми работаете то же в hex, сверяете с массивом и делаете что-то в зависимости от проверки. Если строка начинается с `<?, %, <?php, <?=` соответственно ставите заглушку.

Если кто-то думает, что LFI, RCE пережиток прошлого, то [читайте эту фееричную статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143548/), 2012 год между прочим!

PS. Извиняюсь за слегка сумбурное изложение идеи.